# Definir model o atributo do tipo Array bidimensional

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Existe uma forma de criar um atributo do tipo *array* bidimensional no *Model* para que possa usar esse atributo para montar uma *table* na *View*.

Exemplo: No *model* defino um atributo do tipo *array* bidimensional (`int[,] matriz`) e no *controller* defino que o array será 20x20 e cada posição terá valor X, por exemplo, e na *view* terá um `foreach` percorrendo o *array* para montar uma *table* com o x preenchido em cada célula.

No *Model* criei atributos com várias colunas e no *controller* uso uma lista do tipo enumerable com 20 posições, mas não achei legal pois quero que a montagem do array fosse mais dinâmico.

Comment: Sim, você pode. Coloque seu código para podermos opnar.

Answer (score 0):

> No *Model* criei atributos com várias colunas e no *controller* uso uma lista do tipo enumerable com 20 posições, mas não achei legal pois quero que a montagem do *array* fosse mais dinâmico.

Por definição, *arrays* não são dinâmicos. Se a ideia é ser mais dinâmico, use objetos que trabalhem bem com número variável de índices, como [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) ou [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ainda assim, se você deseja trabalhar com matrizes a nível de *View* pode implementar o *ModelBinder* abaixo:

```
public class TwoDimensionalArrayBinder<T> : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        try
        {
            int totalRows = 0;
            while (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key + totalRows) != null)
                totalRows++;
            ValueProviderResult[] val = new ValueProviderResult[totalRows];
            for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
                val[i] = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key + i);
            if (val.Length > 0)
            {
                int totalColumn = ((string[])val[0].RawValue).Length;
                T[,] twoDimensionalArray = new T[totalRows, totalColumn];
                StringBuilder attemptedValue = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < totalColumn; j++)
                    {
                        twoDimensionalArray[i, j] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(((string[])val[i].RawValue)[j], typeof(T));
                        attemptedValue.Append(twoDimensionalArray[i, j]);
                    }
                }
                bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(key, new ValueProviderResult(twoDimensionalArray, attemptedValue.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                return twoDimensionalArray;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(key, "Data is not in correct Format");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

E usar assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(TwoDimensionalArrayBinder<int>))] int[,] Matriz
{ ... }
```